# Python Avoid method calls if class instantiation object does not exist?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, beautifulsoup

I am writing a class for a web scraper. The class takes a BeautifulSoup object and attempts to find a table with the `id: kFin` (Key Financials).

However, 2 edge cases are possible: The table can either not exist, or the table can exist with 1 or many values available to extract. I can work around the problem if a value does not exist (with the try except in each method) when attempting to fetch it. However, what I am currently stumped on is this question:

"How can I avoid/prevent/return "N/A" if the `kFin` table does not exist from the beginning, in the most pythonic/efficient way possible?"

```
class KeyFinancials:

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page

        #TODO: Implement try except when grabbing Financials table

        table = page.find("table", attrs={'id': 'kFin'})

        head = [element.get_text() for element in table.select('th')]
        rows = [element.get_text() for element in table.select('td')]
        self.data = dict(zip(head, rows))

    def annual_sales(self):
        try:
            return self.data['Annual Sales'].rstrip().lstrip()
        except:
            return "N/A"

    def sales_2015(self):
        try:
            return self.data['2015 Sales'].rstrip().lstrip()
        except:
            return "N/A" 

    def annual_net_income(self):
        try:
            return self.data['Annual Net Income'].rstrip().lstrip()
        except:
            return "N/A"
```

I have about 8 methods like the above in the class. Is there a good way to `return "N/A"` in my `main.py` script if I attempt to call any of the class methods?

Apologies if I am not using terminology 100% correctly here, I am self taught and a team of 1 and have only just begun understanding classes.

Thank you SO much in advance.

Comment: It seems that if the table does not exist, instantiating `KeyFinancials` should probably fail. Is that what you're trying to accomplish? On another note, your class methods include what are called "bare excepts" and can be a sneaky source of bugs. You should almost always specify an exception type to catch -- here, for example, I'm guessing you want `except KeyError:`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bare exceptions, that's a good call! will have to fix it. I think what you are suggesting sounds good, what would be the best way to implement this and return "N/A" if class instantiation fails?

Comment: Well it's a bit unclear to me what you mean by "return N/A". What I would imagine *should* happen is that whenever you try to create an instance, an exception is raised. In your calling code you check for the exception. If it is raised, then you do whatever you'd like: print N/A, a warning message, whatever.

Comment: You're correct, I'm looking to simply return the string `"N/A"` so I can write that value into a .txt file instead of the actual value that I would have liked to fetch. Would you be able to write an answer and show an example of how your solution would be implemented? would there be a `try def __init__`? I can see the logic, I just can't see how it's coded. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to throw an exception if the table couldn't be found when you try to create an instance of your class, then handle the exception in your calling code. In your `__init__`, write:

```
class KeyFinancials:

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page

        table = page.find("table", attrs={'id': 'kFin'})
        if table is None:
            raise ValueError('The table was not found!')
```

Note that if you know about custom exceptions, you might want to use one here, say `MissingTableError`, instead of `ValueError`. If not, no worries.

Now, in your calling code, check for the error whenever you try to create the class:

```
try:
    financials = KeyFinancials(page)
except ValueError:
    # oh no, the page didn't have a table!
    print "N/A"
```

---

Now, your example code doesn't use `page`, except for immediately looking for `table`. Perhaps it would be best to make the only argument to `KeyFinancials.__init__` the table? That way you could write:

```
class KeyFinancials:

    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table
        # ...
```

And do the error-checking in your calling code:

```
table = page.find("table", attrs={'id', 'kFin'})
if table is None:
    print "N/A"
else:
    financials = KeyFinancials(table)
    # ...
```